# Launch jar file from VBA code

Tags: java, vba, sqlite, jar, path

I have a .jar file that it load from SQLite DB some field to show in the frame.

If I run the .jar manually with double click all is fine, but if I run the file with this VBA code:

```
Private Sub Comando8_Click()

   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   strDocuments = WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
   FileName = "\HotelFiller\HotelFiller.jar /foo"
   strDocuments = strDocuments + FileName

   WshShell.Run strDocuments

End Sub
```

The program run but don't load the field from SQLite DB. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

jar is not exe. when you double click a jar file, it works. Just like you click on a txt file, notepad will execute and read the txt file, show the content.

So does jar file. When you double click the jar file, system(Windows I suppose) will launch java.exe, java.exe will launch the jar file and execute the code from jar.

I am not an expert of VB. But you can try to replace `FileName = "\HotelFiller\HotelFiller.jar /foo"` with `FileName = "java -jar \HotelFiller\HotelFiller.jar /foo"`

`java -jar xxx.jar` is what you can use to run a jar in cmd.

### edit at 2017-01-10

Take a look at your VB code. I suppose in the jar, the result is outputted using System.out.println? You need to find a way to launch a process to execute `java -jar \HotelFiller\HotelFiller.jar /foo"`. And get the output from standard output. The way your are using it seems like a literal string assignment.

Comment: Thanks for answer but the problem remain, the program run but don't load the field from SQLite DB.

Comment: yes.. seem my edit above. you need to find a way in VB to launch a java process using the java -jar xxx.jar command.