# How to call java object in VBA with classpath

Tags: vba, ms-access, cmd

We use a CMD to call a PowerShell script. In the PowerShell script, a Java program is called. Both files are in the same directory. I want this all replaced by VBA within Microsoft Access. I have found several related topics but I can't decide whether it is possible or not based on these topics. Topics like [Launch jar file from VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533076/launch-jar-file-from-vba-code)

The CMD contains the following code:

```
SET CLASSPATH=.\yyyyy.jar
powershell .\startscript.ps1
```

The PowerShell script contains the following sample:

```
& java '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="zzzz.keystore"' com.router.router.router.Router -user:... etc.
```

We also run the same Java program in a different setting, only with the use of one .CMD-file. This is made like:

```
SET USR=user
SET CLASSPATH=.\yyyyy.jar
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=zzzz.keystore com.router.router.router.Router -user:%USR% etc.
```

Preferably both PowerShell and CMD become obsolete and the parameters like "-user" are fed with variables from the VBA code.

Does someone have a usable link, example or code? Please advice.

Comment: If you were to launch the jar using a command line, would you know the command (e.g. `java -jar yourJar.jar -yourParameters...`)? If so, you can just build the string in VBA, then use the code in the question you linked to open a shell and execute the program. You may have some path problems (if your jar is based on some env variables that are not available with the fresh shell created by VBA), but if you can launch it from a Windows command prompt, you should automatically inherit all the path variables of your computer.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I have edited the question because we use the same java program also with the help of only a .cmd-file and no PowerShell. Can you derive what code we need to launch the jar from command line? I am not familiar with this way of coding.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to run a command via the command line. It just happens that this command runs `java`, as far as the VBA code is concerned it may run anything that the shell would understand.

A sample code to run a command via a shell in VBA is the following (note there are many ways and it's super easy to find these samples on internet, I'm just using the first one I found):

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = False
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /C " & yourCommand
```

... where `yourCommand` is the litteral string you would run in your command prompt. Now, it's all about string concatenation in VBA. Following your sample (and adding the username directly from VBA):

```
user = Environ("UserName")
yourCommand = "java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=zzzz.keystore com.router.router.router.Router -user:" & user
```

(please note that I replaced `%USR%` - which asks the shell to retrieve the username - with a variable `user` that I've defined in VBA, even though in this specific example, the function `Environ` is asking environment variables so it's still asking it to a shell).

Comment: P.s. I think you may remove the tags java and jar from the question, as it's just a case that you're running a java program and not something else.

Comment: I have used your line of code, changed it into: "java -cp .\yyyyy.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=zzzz.keystore ...etc. It calls the WScript.Shell, but my java program now returns an error: Failed to create temporary file for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll library: not found in resource path. If i run the same code in VBA with the Shell command, the program runs fine. What do I need to change?

Comment: I think your VBA Shell is missing the context defined in the PATH that your normal shell has. You should print the path from a command prompt, and export it into the VBA shell before running the command. Your VBA she’ll is surely missing the path of some executables.

Comment: I have checked the PATH between both normal and VBA Shell, but both are the same. Strangest thing is that when I have ran the cmd seperately from Access, and than calling it through VBA, it works. When I reboot computer and call it directly from VBA without using the CMD seperate first, It returns the error again. Any suggestions where to find the cause for this?

Comment: @Avanasten I think it's a matter of user profiles. When you start the CMD manually, it's loading your user profile and keeping it for next executions. However, the same is not triggered when you run the shell directly from VBA. You should look on internet how to load the profile correctly in vba.

Comment: can you guide me a little bit more into what I should google. I have found information about %userprofile% and checked both cmd's to show content of that variable, both are equal. Didn't find anything more about user permissions etc, do yuou have some links or keywords to help me?

Comment: @Avanasten you understand what [user profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776892(v=vs.85)) are, then you figure out which one is your by default, you search [how to run command line under a specific profile](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001458-13/task/t_command_line_load_profile.htm) and you send your command along with the correct user profile.